# Trying to compile a simple opencv c++ file

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm new to open cv. At the moment I'm trying to test if I could run a simple file.

```
// Example showing how to read and write images
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv/cvaux.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  IplImage * pInpImg = 0;

  // Load an image from file - change this based on your image name
  pInpImg = cvLoadImage("bear.jpg", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_UNCHANGED);
  if(!pInpImg)
  {
    fprintf(stderr, "failed to load input image\n");
    return -1;
  }

  // Write the image to a file with a different name,
  // using a different image format -- .png instead of .jpg
  if( !cvSaveImage("my_image_copy.png", pInpImg) )
  {
    fprintf(stderr, "failed to write image file\n");
  }

  // Remember to free image memory after using it!
  cvReleaseImage(&pInpImg);

  return 0;
}
```

I compiled it:

```
g++ `pkg-config –cflags opencv` cv.cpp -o cv `pkg-config –libs opencv`
```

I got this error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_cvLoadImage", referenced from:
      _main in cv-zQ5X30.o
  "_cvReleaseImage", referenced from:
      _main in cv-zQ5X30.o
  "_cvSaveImage", referenced from:
      _main in cv-zQ5X30.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I'm lost here, any help would be very much appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: Yes, I'm on MacOSX 10.8.5

Comment: @drifterOcean19 try compiling with the -m32 flag added. It looks like you're trying to compile a 64 bit application and link against a 32bit opencv library g++ `pkg-config –cflags opencv` cv.cpp -m32 -o cv `pkg-config –libs opencv`

Comment: Try running `pkg-config –libs opencv` on its own. I don't think it adds "-l" or "-L" at the start, so you may have to add that yourself.

Comment: @MarkSetchell using `pkg-config –libs opencv` works perfectly fine like that...

Comment: @GeorgeProfenza I tried that and I got                           clang: error: no such file or directory: 'pkg-config'
clang: error: no such file or directory: '–cflags'
clang: error: no such file or directory: 'opencv'
clang: error: no such file or directory: 'pkg-config'
clang: error: no such file or directory: '–libs'
clang: error: no such file or directory: 'opencv'

Comment: @MarkSetchell I tried pkg-config –libs opencv and I got nothing?

Comment: @drifterOcean19 do you actually have pkg-config on your system ? You get it on most Linux version, but you need to install it manually on OSX AFAIK. You can however link manually (without having pkg-config figure out the paths for you)

Comment: Aha! That will be the problem then! You have either not installed pkg-config, or you don't have it in your PATH. Did you install it? If not, install it. If you did install it, you must edit your PATH (in ~/.profile) to include the PATH to the directory where it is installed.

Comment: @GeorgeProfenza So I have to install MacPorts for the pkg-config?

Comment: You should be able to compile without pkg-config and manually specify paths if you want to. Have you installed opencv via macports or manually compiled from source ? Can you try something like `g++ -I/usr/include -L/usr/lib -lopencv_core.2.x.x -lopencv_highgui.2.x.x cv.cpp `? (replacing 2.x.x with the version of opencv you use (e.g. 2.4.8))

Comment: @MarkSetchell I believe I already installed the pkg-config : sudo port install pkgconfig and it's done. What do I do next?

Comment: If `pkg-config –libs opencv` still gives no output, try George's suggestion so you don't need `pkg-config` and just build manually.

Comment: @GeorgeProfenza I did this :  g++ -I/usr/include -L/usr/lib -lopencv_core.2.x.x -lopencv_highgui.2.x.x cv.cpp - I think my version is 2.4.3. Is there any way to check what's my version is? I got this : ld: library not found for -lopencv_core.2.4.3
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: @GeorgeProfenza I installed opencv using Homebrew

Comment: any code using IplImge is horribly outdated. please avoid that at all cost.

Comment: @drifterOcean19 Do you have XCode installed ?

Answer (score 1):

i think the problem might be using "-libs" and "-cflags" instead of "--libs" and "--cflags", use this instead:

```
g++ `pkg-config --cflags opencv` cv.cpp -o cv `pkg-config --libs opencv`
```

Comment: I tried that and got clang: error: unsupported option '--cflags'
clang: error: unsupported option '--libs'
clang: error: no such file or directory: 'pkg-config'
clang: error: no such file or directory: 'opencv'
clang: error: no such file or directory: 'pkg-config'
clang: error: no such file or directory: 'opencv'

Comment: @KeillRandor I think you will need to actually execute the `pkg-config` parts, like this `$(pkg-config --cflags opencv)` and `$(pkg-config --libs opencv)`.